# Return whole line where variable is present

Tags: regex, tcl

I have a html document that is stored in the variable $res. In that document there is a specific indside a HTML-tag that contains the word 'house'.

I want the whole line containing the word house to be displayed. How do I use the regexp to do that? I have read this: https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/regexp.htm

But didn't quite find what i'm looking for.

```
set grepfw "house"

set fwversion [regexp -inline "$grepfw" $res]
puts $fwversion
```

Right now if i remove the -inline flag I get "1" returned and if -inline flag is enabled i only get the 'house' returned.

Comment: Can you share a sample of the string you're looking into?

Comment: <tr>
                  <td class='hd'>Software Version:</td>
                  <td>house</td>
 </tr>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're looking to do line-aware matching, pass the `-line` option to `regexp`. Also, you need to add some extra bits around the outside of the regular expression to say that you want to match the line and not just the word. Finally, you need to think about whether you want *just* the word `house`. Would `lighthouseman` be a desired match? If not, you need word boundary constraints (i.e. `\y` in Tcl's RE sub-language).

```
set word "house"

# Backslashes are doubled: we're in double quotes here
# Use [lindex … 0] to strip one (unwanted here) layer of list-ish-ness
set fwversion [lindex [regexp -inline -line "^.*\\y$word\\y.*$" $res] 0]
puts $fwversion
```

Note that *normally* you should not put regular expressions in double quotes as it means you need to add lots of backslashes and that's both hard to read and easy to get wrong. This is the sole real exception: we're building the regular expression dynamically. Though of course there's other options for doing this as well. For example:

```
set RE [format {^.*\y%s\y.*$} $word]
set fwversion [lindex [regexp -inline -line $RE $res] 0]
```

```
set RE [string cat {^.*\y} $word {\y.*$}]
set fwversion [lindex [regexp -inline -line $RE $res] 0]
```

I quite like putting the overall regular expression in a variable. This lets me give a name to the RE which can help a lot with (briefly!) documenting complex matchers in a larger program.

Comment: Thank you - its working with the 'string' solution! :)